# External hard drive files disappeared

Tags: hard-drive

The files in my hard drive is disappeared suddenly after restart computer.

When I plugging the hard drive, it's detected, contain spaces occupied, but I can't find any file even enter `ls -al` in terminal.

The result of `fdisk -l`:

[image: fdisk -l]

I'm using `Ubuntu 16`

---

1st Edit

Result of `df` command is showing my external disk:

`/dev/sdc1      976751316 463861712 512889604  48% /media/lxuancheng/SANSUNG HD`

but `mountpoint /dev/sdc1` is returning `/dev/sdc1 is not a mountpoint`

How can I recover my files?

Comment: Does sdb1 get mounted anywhere? Use df to see if it's mounted.

Comment: Yes, `sdb1` is mounted, I can enter in it, but it's not showing any file

Comment: Since mount points are directories, being able to "enter in it" doesn't necessarily mean the device is mounted.

Comment: @steeldriver How can I check if it's mounted?

Comment: Use `df` like @ubfan1 suggested - or `mountpoint /path/to/dir` where `dir` is where you believe it to be mounted

Comment: @steeldriver I did this test, so it's returning `/dev/sdc1 is not a mountpoint` (I also updated my question with this test result)

Comment: `/dev/sdc1` would be the *block device* not the mountpoint - that would be something like `/media/mydrive` or whatever. Really it's just easier to type `df`.

Comment: So I need use `mountpoint /media/myuser/myHardDisk` ?